# Selecting the Max Date From Multiple Tables

Tags: sql, max

any help would be so incredibly appreciated.  I am trying to select the last activity date from a group of tables.  The tables include  Entry Date, Note date, payment date, and Claim Date.   I would like to return only the max value from all these dates. Furthermore I only want records where there has been no activity for over 45 days.  I am currently using the following SQL to bring all the dates in then using calculated fields in EXCEL to figure the rest out.  Is it possible to do this all with SQL?

Thanks in advance.

```
SELECT xrxTrnLgr.PatId, xrxTrnLgr.Balance, 
       Max(xrxPatNotes.NoteDate) AS 'Max of NoteDate', 
       Max(xrxTrnIcf.PostDate) AS 'Max of IcfPostDate', 
       Max(xrxPat.EntryDate) AS 'Entry Date', 
       Max(xrxPat.Coverage) AS 'Coverage', 
       Max(xrxTrnPay.PostDate) AS 'Last Payment'
  FROM  xrxTrnLgr 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN xrxPatNotes ON xrxTrnLgr.PatId = xrxPatNotes.PatId
  LEFT OUTER JOIN  xrxTrnIcf ON xrxTrnLgr.PatId = xrxTrnIcf.PatId
  LEFT OUTER JOIN xrxPat ON xrxTrnLgr.PatId = xrxPat.PatId
  LEFT OUTER JOIN xrxTrnPay ON xrxTrnLgr.PatId = xrxTrnPay.PatId
  GROUP BY xrxTrnLgr.PatId, xrxTrnLgr.Balance
  HAVING (xrxTrnLgr.Balance>$.01)
```

Comment: What is the problem with the query you posted?

Comment: Which SQL dialect?   mySQL, Microsoft SQL, Oracle, etc?

Answer (score 0):

I think this might do it all in SQL:

```
select t.patid, t.balance,
       max(case when which = 'note' then thedate end) as note,
       max(case when which = 'post' then thedate end) as post,
       max(case when which = 'entry' then thedate end) as entry,
       max(case when which = 'coverage' then thedate end) as coverage,
       max(case when which = 'lastPayment' then thedate end) as lastPayment
from xrxTrnLgr t left join
     ((select patid, notedate as thedate, 'note' as which
       from xrxPatNotes
      ) union all
      (select patid, postdate, 'post'
       from xrxtrnIcf
      ) union all
      (select patid, EntryDate, 'entry'
       from xrxPat
      ) union all
      (select paid, Coverage, 'coverage'
       from xrxPat.Coverage
      ) union all
      (select patid, PostDate, 'LastPayment'
       from xrxTrnPay.PostDate
      ) 
    ) d
    on t.patid = d.patid
group by t.patid, t.balance
having min(now() - thedate) >= 45
```

Comment: It is Microsoft SQL.  I am querying the data from SQL server 2008.  I tried the above code and it did not work.